# Substring Binary Data in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, binary

I have a binary column in my table in mysql. I need to update all the rows for example.

Replace 2nd byte with 1. Doesn't matter what the value was.

```
SELECT HEX(data) FROM table;
```

Then

```
UPDATE table SET data[1] = 1; // the idea
```

But how do you do something like this in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how you can do it. First get the binary representation with `hex` function.
Then on the returned value use `substring` and `concat` function to replace the 2nd value with `1` and finally update.

Here is an example.

```
CREATE TABLE t (c BINARY(10));
INSERT INTO t SET c = 'b';

select (HEX(c)) from t;

62000000000000000000

SELECT concat(
  substring(HEX(c),1,1),
  '1',
  substring(HEX(c),3,length(HEX(c)))

) 
from t

61000000000000000000
```

Now putting all together in the update command will replace the value

```
update t set c = unhex(
  concat(
    substring(HEX(c),1,1),
    '1',
    substring(HEX(c),3,length(HEX(c)))
  ) 
);

select (HEX(c)) from t;
61000000000000000000
```

Comment: a good trick, but why doesn't mysql have something for this, sql-server has.